# Getting the request URL of a SOAP request in handleResponse Method in ClientInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, resttemplate

I am using spring boot. I have written a ClientInterceptor for a SOAP web service and i would like to log the URL that i am sending my request to, and i would like to do it in the handleResponse method. However i could not find a way to do it. Is it possible? Any help would be great.

```
public class SoapClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

@Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        // I would like to get the URL and log it here. 

    }

}
```

The way i create the restTemplate

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("testRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate testRestTemplate() {

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);
    ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(restClientHttpRequestInterceptor));
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(testErrorHandler);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your handleResponse method:

```
TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
context.getConnection().getUri().toString()
```

i hope this helps you